# Copying some files to a zip file sub directory without extracting it using C#

Tags: c#, zip, c#-ziparchive

I have a zip file which contains sub directories and files. I want to copy a file to  this zip sub directory. I'm able to copy this directly to zip but I want to copy to the zip sub directory.

This is my code snippet.

```
 public void CopyToZip(string zipFile, string folderToZip)
    {           
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {                
            string[] di = Directory.GetFiles(folderToZip,"*.config",SearchOption.AllDirectories);                                
            if (di != null && di.Length > 0)
            {                    
                foreach (string fileToArchive in di)
                {
                    zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToArchive, "*.config", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please stop suggesting that reading from a zip file is the same as adding to it. Adding to a zip file - if you want good compression - requires complete recompression of all the files in the archive.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes you're right. But if I wants to change a single file from the zip file, if possible just copy that file and do the changes then copy back to the zip can save some time, right ?

Comment: Zip files are compressed by creating a dictionary of bit sequences that occur often across all the files in the archive. When you add a file, that dictionary should change, meaning that all the files would need to be compressed again. If the file you add is similar to the existing files you might get OK results reusing the existing dictionary. But if you want optimal compression, you need to create a new dictionary and recompress all the files.